# Is there to set screen resolution/screen density by app?

Tags: screen-resolution

I have a rooted Z3 compact running Android 5.0.2.

I've been using the Resolution Changer app to set my screen resolution, as I find it makes a huge difference in screen real estate and aesthetics. But a couple of apps don't seem to like it (menus appear strange, some text not displayed at all etc).

Is there a way (app, setting etc) to make it so that specific apps run on specific resolutions or at least, a screen resolution/density changer that lets you choose apps on which to ignore that setting?

My goal is to be able to have a specific resolution set for certain apps and have others display in the original resolution my phone has in its factory setting.

I'm hoping that's possible as I remember running custom ROMs on previous Android phones I've had that had different resolutions for some applications.

Comment: If you have xposed installed, App Settings does exactly that: Allow the DPI to be set for each app individually.

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure I do, mind linking to a guide?

Comment: Then you don't have it (you have to install it separately). You can find out more about xposed on xda-developers: http://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed